# How do you read 0.1 and 0.24 and 1 4/5 aloud in American English?

Tags: reading-aloud, word-stress

> 0.1
>
> 0.24
>
> 1 4/5

How do you read them and is there any differences in American and British?

Comment: It partly depends on the overall context. For example, I normally pronounce _.283_ as "point two eight three". However, if we are talking about A-Rod's batting average, I would say "two eighty-three".

Answer (score 3):

I am a native British English speaker who has worked in an engineering environment in the US. I do not recall these numbers being pronounced differently between continents.

I would say:

> 0.1 *Oh point one* -or- *one tenth*
>
> 0.24 *Oh point two four*
>
> 1 <sup>4</sup>/<sub>5</sub> *One and four fifths*

(However I'm prepared to be corrected by other engineers with multinational experience)

Comment: The leading zero is sometimes pronounced as "zero" instead of "oh".

Comment: .. and thinking about it some Brits would say "nought"...

Comment: Brian: Oh, good point. One problem with questions like this one is that there is rarely one and only one "correct' or "proper" way to say these numbers aloud. Sometimes the zero doesn't get mentioned at all, as in: _"point two four"_